# php best way to negate string of bits

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I have an array of string bits of variable length and I need to negate them.

eg.

input `array("1", "00101", "101", "0000")`

output `array("0", "11010", "010", "1111")`

Is there a simple way how to do that?

Comment: What datatype do you have? Are these really bits or a string representation?

Comment: If it's just strings, then [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr). (Eh, use it properly, with swap strings, not array params.)

Comment: could you please provide some code considering the actual format of your input? e. g. `$bits=array("1", "00101");`

Comment: Bitwise XOR operator: `$negate = $value ^ 0xFFFFFFFF`, if your values are integers.

Comment: it is an array of string bits, question edited

Comment: @mario: `strtr(..., [1, 0])` will be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function:

```
$bites = array("1", "00101", "101", "0000");

$output = array_map(function($element){
    return strtr($element, array('1', '0'));
}, $bites);

print_r($output);
```

Comment: This works fine. But it is slower then marios answer with only strtr($element, "1", "0").

Comment: I edit my answer. But you must to know this is not a bit operation but string manipulation.

Comment: You are right. But this is still slower then simple strtr($element, "1", "0"). When I tested in on 100000 values it needed 200% of the time.

Comment: You must define two ways mapping between strings, that mean you must define mapping `1 => 0` and `0 => 1`, there is not other way...

Comment: I tested it and it generates the same output. `var_dump(strtr($element, array('1' => '0', '0' => '1')));`  and `var_dump(strtr($element, "10", "01"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $negate = intval($value, 2) ^ 0x7FFFFFFF;
    echo base_convert(strval($negate), 10, 2);
}
```

This code will process all integers in range 0..2<sup>31</sup>-1. Since PHP doesn't support unsigned integers, 2<sup>31</sup>-1 is maximal value that can be processed on all platforms (i.e. 32-bit and 64-bit).

You can use values up to 2<sup>63</sup>-1, if your code is guaranteed to run on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: I need to negate bits from length 1 to lenth 64.

Comment: You can use values up to 2^63-1, if your code is guaranteed to run on 64-bit platforms. But, I think, the other answer is more correct for you, since it let to process numbers of any length.

Comment: I tested it and if I put string 0 and the answer is not 1 but 1111111111111111111111111111111.

Comment: If we are talking about integers instead of strings, it's correct result, since 0 is actually binary 00000000000000000000000000000000. :)

Comment: true, but it doesnt solve my problem :) But it works fine for your point of view on the problem.